# How to return a mapped array in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, return, rendering

I have imported some dummyData (1000 objects of films) to my React.js Component and I want to render the titles.

```
export const dummyData = [
  {
    id: 'tt0111161',
    rank: '1',
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
  }
```

I have created an array with the whole object and I wish to show the first 3 movies.

```
const likedFilms = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    likedFilms.push(dummyData);
}
```

The issues I am having is to render the title.

I have tried using this. and without. Not sure how to access this data...

```
return (
        <div>
    {likedFilms.map((likedFilm) => <p>TITLE: {likedFilms.title} </p>)}
 </div> )

or TITLE: {this.likedFilms.title}
```

Mapping does work as it shows me:
TITLE:
TITLE:
TITLE:

But it doesnt render the title.

Comment: its because you push `dummyData`, it should be `likedFilms.push(dummyData[i])`

Comment: also, your JSX mapping should return `<p>TITLE: {likedFilm.title}</p>` (you want to return particular items, not the whole array every time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your return, you are accessing likedFilm**S** instead of likedFilm, in the example I've changed the name to film

```
{likedFilms.map(film => <p>TITLE: {film.title} </p>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{likedFilms.map((likedFilm) => <p>TITLE: {likedFilm.title} </p>)}
```

`likedFilmed` is the name of your array whereas `likedFilm` is the name of each item in the array when you are iterating. So inside the map's return, you want to access the individual item's property `likedFilm.title` instead of `likedFilms`

I also recommend giving a key to the `p` element to get rid of React's console warning; so assuming the film titles are unique, it would become

```
{likedFilms.map((likedFilm) => <p key={likedFilm.title}>TITLE: {likedFilm.title} </p>)}
```